# Passing a matrix through multiple functions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

A little complicated but I'll try to explain best I can, but I have values I am trying to calculate that are based on two other functions with multiple inputs. In the code below, my inputs are various theta values which then should create an array of m & n values. From the m & n arrays, I then need to calculate the various Q_bar terms which should output an array for each term as well.

```
theta = np.array([0, 25, -80, 90, 20])

m = math.cos(math.radians(theta)) #[deg]
n = math.sin(math.radians(theta)) #[deg]

Q_bar11 = Q11*(m**4) + 2*(Q12 + 2*Q66)*(n**2)*(m**2) + Q22*(n**4)
Q_bar12 = (Q11 + Q22 - 4*Q66)*(n**2)*(m**2) + Q12*(n**4 + m**4)
Q_bar16 = (Q11 - Q12 - 2*Q66)*n*(m**3) + (Q12 - Q22 + 2*Q66)*(n**3)*m
Q_bar22 = Q11*(n**4) + 2*(Q12 + 2*Q66)*(n**2)*(m**2) + Q22*(m**4)
Q_bar26 = (Q11 - Q12 - 2*Q66)*(n**3)*m + (Q12 - Q22 + 2*Q66)*n*(m**3)
Q_bar66 = (Q11 + Q22 - 2*Q12 - 2*Q66)*(n**2)*(m**2) + Q66*(n**4 + m**4)
```

I've seen similar posts about passing arrays through functions however I have not been successful in implementing them, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, could you show us what type of functions will take the arrays as inputs?

Comment: Finish your post with a sentence that asks a question, please. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Be careful.  `math.sin/cos` only work with scalars, single numbers.  For arrays use `np.sin/cos`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a list into function. pass each values differently might help!

```
    deg = np.array([math.cos(math.radians(theta[i])) for i in range(5)])

    news = pd.Series(theta,deg)
```

Sorry, I couldn't understand the q part exactly but if you explain it deeper than I'll try to help it too

Comment: Haha yeah sorry if it was vague, hard to explain the Q_bar terms but basically I'm performing a composite material analysis so there's a lot of terms that make up matrices. The Q terms are just values I need to find in order to properly analyze the material.

Comment: Also, gave your code a go however it is only outputting a single value and not a 5 x 1 matrix like the input

Comment: [1.00000000e+00 9.06307787e-01 1.73648178e-01 6.12323400e-17
 9.39692621e-01] it outputs like this, I guess your work is above my understanding sorry

Comment: i edited and do it much as I uunderstand,could you please check again